# Кеширование файлов с помощью JavaScript

Tags: javascript, кэширование

Имеется определённый массив путей на `.css`, `.ttf`, `.jpg` и т.п. файлы. Как загрузить их так, чтобы при создании элементов, использующих эти файлы (например, `div` со свойством `background-size: url(image.jpg)`), браузер не загружал их заново?

Answer (score 1):

Тебе не надо об этом задумываться. Браузер это делает за тебя автоматически, при условии что ты не выключил кеширование. DevTools вкладка Network, покажет что и откуда загружаются. Еще можешь настроить кеширование в .htaccess или в nginx, в зависимости что у тебя за вебсервер.

Comment: Фишка в том, что пока файлы будут загружаться, будет отображаться анимация загрузки. Только после полной загрузки всех файлов нужно перестроить DOM. Можно сделать стандартным способом, но ставить отдельные обработчики на 15 файлов не очень-то хочется. Тем более, что некоторые из них - картинки, используемые только в CSS и шрифты. DOMContentLoaded в этом случае не подходит.

Comment: Сделай список ресурсов, создавай элементы вручную document.createElement, добавляй слушателя addEventListener на событие load. Когда все загрузится, делай что хочешь.

Comment: Предположим. Тогда как загружать шрифты?

Comment: Ну загрузи файл как угодно, хоть через ajax. Хоть на скрытом канвасе напиши что-то этим шрифтом.

Comment: Тогда как отловить момент, когда шрифт загрузится?

Comment: При успешном выполнении ajax запроса ты получишь ответ в коллбеке, это оно и есть.

Comment: Подождите, а на что тогда ставить обработчик?

Comment: $.get("fon-url").done(res => console.log("loaded"));

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.